# Weird intermittent error occures while sending messages using NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

We are seeing very strange intermittent error in our logs with the NServiceBus code stack trace

NServiceBus version that we are using is 3.3.4

Here the stack trace of the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at NServiceBus.MessageHeaders.MessageHeaderManager.NServiceBus.MessageMutator.IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages.MutateOutgoing(Object[] messages, TransportMessage transportMessage)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.InvokeOutgoingTransportMessagesMutators(Object[] messages, TransportMessage result)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.MapTransportMessageFor(Object[] rawMessages, TransportMessage result)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(List`1 addresses, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(Address address, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IBus.Send(Object[] messages)
```

Any ideas what is the issue ?
Our production code from time to time fails because of this and we need to know why.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be an issue with duplicate subscriptions?

Comment: I think it's related to this one https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1976 even though that issue mentions v4. Are you doing those sends from a message handler or from a MVC controller or similar?

Comment: We are doing sends from both MVC controllers and handlers. I think that the error most probably is triggered when sending from controllers. Need to look through the logs to see if it is thrown from the handlers as well.

Comment: Just an update on this i could not find any errors while sending from handlers. Any ideas what can be the issue ?

Comment: Confirmed. This is happening when sending messages in MVC controllers. Any ideas why ?